# Retina image is looking darker in chrome

Tags: css, retina

[image: imageuploadimg.png][imageuploadimg@2x.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7vDt.png)

I have set a retina background image for a div.Its displaying properly in firefox but its looking darker in chrome.How to fix this issue?
Refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55aLM/1/)

[image: Output-Difference between chrome and firefox]

**Html**

```
<div class="retina_img">

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.retina_img
 {
    background: url("imageuploadimg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 50% / 100% 100% #FFFFFF;
    background:-webkit-image-set( url('imageuploadimg.png') 1x,url('imageuploadimg@2x.png') 2x);
    width: 142px;
    height: 101px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where the issue can be seen?

Comment: Does the image file have any color profile information embedded …?

Comment: I have updated in fiddle.please check it. @Nathan Lee

Comment: cannot see it on your post. Do recheck @RamaPriya

Comment: Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/55aLM/1/

Comment: cannot see any difference on your image. It works fine here. - @RamaPriya

Comment: Have you verified in chrome & firefox?I have attached the screenshot of my output.please check it. @Nathan Lee